An alternate history with some characters purely invented, some historical characters but some historical events are different from in our reality
I remember just one detail of this (IRCC) long and complicated "alternate history" novel which I read so long ago I don't remember when. Except that even though lot of events are common with our history, quite a few are different.
One of the main characters, purely fictitious, has fought (against France, mostly probably) under the orders of the Duke  of Marlborough, the one about whom the Frenchmen, with a lot wishful thinking, invented a song where he first "s'en va-t-en guerre" (is off to war) and then is "mort et enterrré" (dead and buried), while in fact he won battle after battle. What is remarkable about this character, still under the orders of the Duke, is that though the latter keeps telling him not to call him by his first name, he keeps doing it and is not flogged to death for being so casual with his commander. The Duke's first name, I have since checked, is John.

The Duke of Marlborough features in Stephenson's book The System of the World which is indeed a long and complicated alternate history. Marlborough is referred to as Corporal John by his men, though not to his face, and I don't remember the protagonist being overly casual with him.

On page 72 of this version of Quicksilver, Jack Shaftoe alls "Churchill" a character who is not yet the Duke of Marlborough but will become him.  https://neal-stephenson.freenovelread.com/page,72,388081-the_baroque_cycle_quicksilver_the_confusion_and_the_system_of_the_world  I am pretty sure that when Jack meets the same person again, when the latter has been made Duke, he calls him at best Churchill, maybe John. The Duke is not pleased, but does not react as angrily as a Duke might when so addressed by such a commoner.

@JohnRennie   Thanks for reminding me of the name of the full novel, which allowed me to find the appropriate page of Quicksilver (well, not quite the exact page I remembered, but close enpough). Why don't you change your comment into an answer ?

You are remembering Neal Stephenson's Baroque Cycle books. It is an alternate history, and at 2650 pages it's certainly long and complicated.
It's Bob Shaftoe - brother of Jack Shaftoe, "Half-Cocked Jack", a London street urchin turned swashbuckling adventurer and legendary King of the Vagabonds - who meets the future Duke of Marlborough, John Churchill, and becomes familiar with him. Bob Shaftoe becomes a sergeant in Churchill's army and Churchill uses him for various dirty deeds and treats him as a friend. In the second book The Confusion Shaftoe tells Captain Barnes:

“You want a brute for a sergeant, so that he can go do the mopping-up while you wring your hands and disavow his unchivalrous deeds,” Bob said. “For that type of sergeant you must look in a common regiment. But we were organized by Churchill—”
“The Earl of Marlborough, to you!”
“In truth, to me he is John. But whatever he is called, he has odd tastes in sergeants, and though he has been replaced by de Zwolle, you are stuck with me—unless you would care to promote another from the ranks.”
“You’ll do, Sergeant Shaftoe.”


That's exactly it. What I remembered was the juxtaposition "John" and “The Earl of Marlborough, to you!” My memory was a bit garbled, the order was inverted, it was not Jack Shaftoe but his brother Bob, who was not addressing John Churchill but discussing him with a third party. Also the former ( ? not "latter" , that was Barnes, but "former" should be Shaftoe ?) was not yet Duke but at that time only Earl. But it was this precise dialogue. Thanks !

Perhaps worth noting that Bobby Shafto is himself a character from a folk song.
